# Efficiently adding column to dataframe based on values from regex capture groups from other columns

Tags: r, loops

I wanted to add an additional column to an existing dataframe where the value
of *newColumn* would be based on a capture group of a regex applied to another value in the same row and the only thing I came up with that worked so far was this (probably not R-esque) standard-approach of looping but it is awefully slow (for a DF of around 1.5 million rows).

Dataframe with Columns:

```
ID    Text    NewColumn
```

Atm I work with this:

```
df$newColumn <- rep("", nrow(df));
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$newColumn[row] <- str_match(df$Text[row], regex)[1,2];
}
```

I tried using apply/lapply after reading several posts but none of my approaches created the expected result. Is this even possible with a function of the apply-family, and if yes: how?

Example:

for

```
regex <- "^[0-9]*([a-zA-Z]*)$";
```

and a table like the following:

```
ID   Text         
------------------
1    231Ben
2    112Claudine
3    538Julia
```

I would expect:

```
ID   Text          NewColumn
----------------------------
1    231Ben          Ben
2    112Claudine     Claudine
3    538Julia        Julia
```

Comment: Added  a small example; I hope this helps to explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: Have you considered `gsub("\\d+", "", df1$Text)#[1] "Ben"      "Claudine" "Julia"`  Also with `str_match` it would be `str_match(df1$Text, "([A-Za-z]+)")[,1]`

Comment: Much better runtime! That's incredible! If you post that as an answer I will accept; thanks a lot :) I wouldn't have thought that looping would cause such an overhead (I'm everything else than proficient in R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str_match` and `gsub/sub` etc are vectorized, so we don't have to loop through the rows if the `pattern` is the same

```
df1$NewColumn <- gsub("\\d+", "", df1$Text)
```

---

Or with `stringr` functions

```
library(stringr)
df1$NewColumn <- str_match(df1$Text, "([A-Za-z]+)")[,1] 

str_extract(df1$Text, "[A-Za-z]+")
#[1] "Ben"      "Claudine" "Julia"
```